# How to set a boolean array with a fixed size in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way that I can set a boolean array with a fixed size in Objective C ? Would it be easier to do it with a C style ? 
For example, if I want to create a boolean array of the size 10 with all the value set to false. In C++, I would do: `bool arr[10] = {false};`. How would I do that in objective c ?

Thanks

Comment: boolean array means?any example?

Comment: Objective C is an extension of C. Anything you can do in C you can do in Objective-C in exactly the same way.

Comment: The premise is the same as the duplicate, but you can substitute `NSInteger` with `bool` and `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` with just `@NO` or `@YES` etc etc